Transparent image texture occludes translucent texture in Cycles
For some reason, whenever I overlay this image with a transparent background over this transparent texture, it occludes it. This issue only occurs in Cycles. I'm not sure why this is happening. I've tried changing the blend modes and the transparency samples, but nothing seems to work. Does anybody know of a solution?



Go to the material settings of the transparent image.
Is "Blend Mode" set to "Alpha Blend" or "Alpha Hashed" in the material settings is the "Show Backface" option disabled?
